# GLSL Color XY wont work when its not first

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

I have a problem with my Fragment Shader im new i try to make a simple Color Picker but the z in vec3 dont with each Fragment. On this code everything works fine without:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 uResolution;


out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
   vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution;
   vec3 color = rgb2hsb(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
   color = hsb2rgb(vec3(st.xy, color.z));
   fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

And looks like this:

[image]

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 uResolution;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution;
    vec3 color = rgb2hsb(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    color = hsb2rgb(vec3(color.x, st.xy));
    fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

And then its look like this:

[image]

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What do you expect to see?

Comment: It is very likely that `uResolution` is not set and is (0, 0).

Comment: I expected something like this https://gyazo.com/38a2d5b5817ecf51e77022b44e3f6372

Comment: @Emil Yes, I know. You want get it as long as you not set `uResolution`